# Rounding numbers based on decimals value excel

Tags: excel, decimal, rounding, dataformat

I have problem in Excel which i couldn't handle on my own.
So, I have a datasheet in "dd.mm.rrrr hh:mm" format, which shows when a particular process has been finished. When i want to subtract these values to get info how long did it take i will get results like: 6,666667 or 3,33333 or 7,14242.

So i would like to extract integer and then, basing on condition add 0 or 0,5 or 1 to this value. Something like that:
If decimal is higher than 0,5 -> add 1,
If decimal is between 0,3 and 0,5 then add 0,5,
If decimal is lower than 0,3  then add 0 to Integer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try a formula along these lines:

```
=A1+IF(MOD(A1,1)>0.5,1,IF(MOD(A1,1)>=0.3,0.5,0))
```

[image]

Comment: Hi teylyn, your answer is really helpful, you solved given problem, but in terms of me incorporating it to spreadsheet I encounter following problem:
When I subtract two datas; subtracting  23.03.2020 14:00 from 25.03.2020 6:00 i will get 2 days, while it should be 1,5 days of work.  Our first shift is 6-14 and second shift is 14-22. Can you give me a tip which i can implement to my sheet?

Comment: You asked about Problem A, which you think will solve Problem B, but it doesn't. So, don't ask questions about what you THINK might be the solution, i.e. round numbers. Ask the question about the REAL problem, i.e. how to calculate total work days based on your company's shift hours. 
This question has been answered as asked and you should accept the answer. After that, you can ask a new question where you detail your actual problem.

Comment: Thank you for a feedback and your effort. Please apologize my behaviour, have a good day

Answer (score 0):

[Excel screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/S08Qg.png)

Sorry for a confusion. I would like to clarify my problem. My company works on 2 shifts 6:00 - 14:00 and 14:00 - 22:00. We have processes. I would like to get calendar days of subtract:
A) Last Operation and Entrance times
and then compare this time to added consecutive difference between sum of consecutive subtracting:
B) Entrance and Operation2, operation2 and operation3, operation 3 and operation 4 etc. But when I do It my A) time differ from B) time. I have no idea how to deal with it.

Comment: Please learn how this site works. Don't post an answer if you have more questions or want to provide clarification. To do that, edit your original question.